# Android: change title in ActionBar from Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title, navigation-drawer

I created an app with `Navigation Drawer` in `BaseActivity`. Everything works ok except the change of title in the `Action Bar`. the title changes for a second but when opening the new activity is shown the original title.

What can be the error? thanks

**BaseActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PerfilAdapter.iniciarBaseDatos(this);
    perfilObj = PerfilAdapter.selectPerfil(1);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    cargarActionBar();
    cargarDrawerLayout(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menuOpcSonidos:

                   ...
                   return true;

    case R.id.menuOpcCambiarColor:
        ...
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.findItem(R.id.menuOpcSonidos)
        .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.sonidoOnOff) + " " + perfilObj.getSonidos());

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void cargarActionBar() {

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    int[] colores2 = Modulo.cargarColoresDrawerlayout(perfilObj.getColor());
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, colores2));

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    TextView textoTitulo = (TextView)findViewById(titleId);
    textoTitulo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
    textoTitulo.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textoTitulo.setTextSize(19);
    textoTitulo.setShadowLayer(5, 0, 0, getResources().getColor(R.color.negro));        
}

private void cargarDrawerLayout(Bundle b) {

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    textosMenuLateral = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    iconosMenuLateral1 = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.iconos_menu_lateral1);

    iconosMenuLateral2 = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.iconos_menu_lateral2);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenuMain);

    int[] colores = {0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0};
    mDrawerList.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colores));
    mDrawerList.setDividerHeight(4);

    navDrawerItems1 = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

    navDrawerItems1.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[0], iconosMenuLateral1.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems1.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[1], iconosMenuLateral1.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems1.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[2], iconosMenuLateral1.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems1.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[3], iconosMenuLateral1.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    navDrawerItems1.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[4], iconosMenuLateral1.getResourceId(4, -1)));

    navDrawerItems2 = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

    navDrawerItems2.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[0], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems2.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[1], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems2.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[2], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems2.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[3], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    navDrawerItems2.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[4], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(4, -1)));

    iconosMenuLateral1.recycle();
    iconosMenuLateral2.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems1,
            navDrawerItems2,
            perfilObj.getColor(),
            pos);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, 
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.icono_drawer, 
            R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } 

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (b == null) {

        opcionesPanelLateral(0);
    }

}

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);    

        opcionesPanelLateral(position);
    }
}

private void opcionesPanelLateral(int position) {

    Intent i;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            pos = 0;
            break;

        case 1:
            i = new Intent(this, ActivitySecond.class);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            startActivity(i);
            pos = 1;
            break;

        case 2:
            i = new Intent(this, ActivityThird.class);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            startActivity(i);
            pos = 2;
            break;

        case 3:
            i = new Intent(this, ActivityFourth.class);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            startActivity(i);
            pos = 3;
            break;

        case 4:

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(pos, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(pos);

    setTitle(textosMenuLateral[pos]);


    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}


@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    cargarActionBar();
    cargarDrawerLayout(savedInstanceState);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void onBackPressed() {

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

I think that error is the use the Activities... but I don't know as fix

Comment: Maybe because you're setting ActionBar's title twice: One in the `onDrawerClosed` method and the other in `onDrawerOpened`. So, the title will be overwritten with the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio allows to add a navigation drawer to the app through **File | New | Activity**. This "ready-made" navigation drawer comes with everything you need: properties, methods, events, etc.

Next steps to change titles for different fragments are intended to use with the ready-made navigation drawer of Android Studio, but they might be helpful to anyothers:

1. The navigation drawer has several files : one activity, and one or
   more fragments. Open the java activity file of your navigation drawer (what
   you call "Base Activity").
2. Find method **onCreate**.
3. In this method, add the line **mTitle = "???"**, where "???" is the title of
   the first fragment that will me shown as soon as the navigation drawer
   screen appears.
4. Now find method **onNavigationDrawerItemSelected**. CHARLIE, I'm not sure,
   but I believe you have it under the name **opcionesPanelLateral**.
5. In this method you have a **switch**. This switch opens the appropiate
   fragment depending on the selected option. To **set** the title for each
   fragment, go to each **case** in the switch an add the line **mTitle = "My
   title";** before **frg = new my_frag();**. This way, when the fragment opens
   it will show the appropiate title.
6. Find method **restoreActionBar**. CHARLIE, I don't see it in your code
   nor any equivalent method. Add it. Inside of it, add the line
   **actionBar.setTitle( mTitle);**, and here is where the title is actually
   set (maybe that's why your title disappears). Call this method inside
   **onCreateOptionsMenu** (after inflate).

That's it. I'm using hard-coded strings, if you follow Android rules, use strings.xml.

Now a real life example from and app I'm working on right now. Next is the raw code of my "BaseActivity" of the ready-made navigation drawer (some things are in spanish because I'm costarrican):

```
package my_package;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class menu_act extends    ActionBarActivity
                      implements drawer_frg.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
private drawer_frg mNavigationDrawerFragment;
// Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
private CharSequence mTitle;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
setContentView( R.layout.menu_lay );

mNavigationDrawerFragment = (drawer_frg) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                                                       R.id.navigation_drawer );
mTitle = "Perfil"; // getTitle();

// Set up the drawer.
mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp( R.id.navigation_drawer,( DrawerLayout )
                                           findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout ) );

// BARRA DE TÍTULO ANARANJADA.
//ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( getResources().getColor( R.color.col_nar ) ) );
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected ( int position ) {
Fragment frg;
// getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions( ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM );
switch ( position )
{ case 0  : //getSupportActionBar().setCustomView( R.layout.perfil_tit );
            mTitle = "Perfil";
            frg = new perfil_frg();
            break;
  case 1  : // getSupportActionBar().setCustomView( R.layout.contactos_tit );
            mTitle = "Contactos";
            frg = new contactos_frg();
            break;
  default : frg = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance( position + 1 );
}
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.container,frg ).commit();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void onSectionAttached ( int number ) {
switch (number) {
  case 1 : mTitle = getString( R.string.mnu_opc_per ); break;
  case 2 : mTitle = getString( R.string.mnu_opc_con ); break;
  case 3 : mTitle = getString( R.string.mnu_opc_sal ); break;
}
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void restoreActionBar () {
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD );
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( true );
actionBar.setTitle( mTitle );
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
if ( ! mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen() )
   { // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
     // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
     // decide what to show in the action bar.
     getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.menu_act,menu );
     restoreActionBar();
     return true;
   }
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
/*
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if ( id == R.id.action_settings )
     return true;
*/
//mDrawerToggle.syncState();
return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
}
//==============================================================================
// A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The fragment argument representing the section number for this fragment.
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public PlaceholderFragment() {
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_frg, container, false);
return rootView;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
((menu_act) activity).onSectionAttached( getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
}
//==============================================================================
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: what is mTitle itself? Is it String? because it shows red line.

Comment: @ImranAslam, "mTitle" is declared at the top of my code (below "public class menu_act") : `private CharSequence mTitle;` .